# accepts_nested_attributes_for and second-order associations, nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have following models with associations:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :guests
  has_many :customers, :through => :guests
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customers
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :guests
   has_many :orders, :through => :guests
   has_many :slips
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :slips
end

class Slip < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :order
   belongs_to :customer
end

class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

My nested form looks like this:

```
<!-- general form -->
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
    <% f.fields_for :customers do |builder| %>
        <%= render "customer_fields", :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<!-- partial customer_fields -->
<p>
    <%= f.label :name%><%= f.text_field :name %>
    <% f.fields_for :slips do |builder| %>
        <%= render "slip_fields", :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
</p>

<!-- partial slip_fields -->
<p><%= f.label :quantity%><%= f.text_field :quantity %></p>
```

With this setup saving an order works as expected, but I need the order_id to be saved with the slip, so I have a reference between order <-> slip. With this setup I loose the reference. I can get all associated customers, but I'll get all associated slips of the customer related to the order or not.

---

Here the fields of my models:
Order -> id
Customer -> id
Guest -> id, order_id, customer_id
Slip -> id, order_id, customer_id

---

The result of an order should look like this

- Order

  1. Customer A

     - Slip 1
     - Slip 2
  2. Customer B

     - Slip 1
     - Slip 2
  3. Customer A

     - Slip 1
     - Slip 2
     - Slip 3

---

I've no idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: I can imagine how to do it for exist @order, but for new Order it is very complicated. You can use old school virtual attributes for nested resources but not modern `accepts_nested_attributes_for` here

Comment: Maybe there is a hook where I can pass the order_id to the slip model?

Comment: I've added a comment to explain solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you can't return `order_id` for order that isn't exist you can do this hook (I haven't test it, so you'll maybe need to fix it)

```
def create
  customers = params[:order].delete :customers_attributes
  @order = Order.new params[:order]
  if @order.save
    customers.each{|c| c[:slips_attributes].each{|s| s[:order_id] = @order.id} }
    @order.customers_attributes = customers
    @order.save
  end
end

def update
  @order = Order.find params[:id]
  params[:order][:customers_attributes].each{|c| c[:slips_attributes].each{|s| s[:order_id] = @order.id} }
  @order = Order.update_attributes params[:order]
  @order.save
end
```

Also you'd better to remove all this logic into your model and you can `dry` it a little. This only about understanding an approach.

**UPD** for your ID collisions. It is only a scetch again

```
def create
  customers = params[:order].delete :customers_attributes
  @order = Order.new params[:order]
  @order.customer_ids = customers.inject([]){|a,h| a << h[:b] if h[:b]; a}
  if @order.save
    customers.each{|c| c[:slips_attributes].each{|s| s[:order_id] = @order.id} }
    @order.customers_attributes = customers
    @order.save
  end
end

def update
  @order = Order.find params[:id]
  @order.customer_ids = params[:order][:customers_attributes].inject([]){|a,h| a << h[:b] if h[:b]; a}
  params[:order][:customers_attributes].each{|c| c[:slips_attributes].each{|s| s[:order_id] = @order.id} }
  @order = Order.update_attributes params[:order]
  @order.save
end
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked for me, although I had to change:
customers.each{|c| c[:slips_attributes].each{|s| s[:order_id] = @order.id} }
to
customers.values.each{|c| c[:slips_attributes].values.each{|s| s[:order_id] = @order.id} }

Comment: Now clean your controllers and dry your methods. Remove all this stuff into model :)

Comment: Thx, yeah, I'll try. Now I get another error: if I try to add an existing customer I get this message: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Customer with ID=1 for Order with ID=7):

Comment: what do you mean `If I try to add an existing customer`. You have got kind of a select field to choose customer or what?

Comment: try to deeply understand what is going under the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` magick: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes

Comment: I do an ajax request and fill the fields with the returned data. I've a hidden field for the ID of the customer. If there is an id I get the error.

Comment: that's absolutely another issue from our first discussion. ANd this is again how it works. :)If you will try to send :id of an object Rails will try TO FIND IT AND UPDATE IT. So you need to prereattach it to your object before you will call `@order.customers_attributes = customers` or `@order = Order.update_attributes params[:order]`

Comment: I've updated my answer to demonstrait new approach of prereattaching customers to an order

Comment: I'm really thankful for your help. What I did so far is creating the association manually:
if(!c[:id].nil?) then
  @guest = Guest.new
  @guest.order_id = @order.id
  @guest.customer_id = c[:id]
  @guest.save
end

But now I get 2 entries in the guests table. One missing the customer_id. I totally have no clue. I think I should have a break :)

Comment: some kind of. I'm little confused in your DB architecture. I think you can refactore and improve your db. And it would be easier to use this way :)